# js: create an array that holds the indexof duplicates in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I'm looking for a js/jquery solution for the following

I want to check an array for duplicates, lets say:

```
var destRes = ['BH17 7EP', 'TA2 6LL', 'OX15 4LJ', 'OX15 4LJ', 'OX15 4LJ', 'BH17 7EP', 'TA2 6LL']
```

and return an array that holds the first index of that value;
for example for the above ex this should be the return:

```
var newArr = ['0', '1', '2', '2', '2', '0', '1' ]
```

`BH17 7EP` is at index `0` and `5`, so in the new array the `0` and the `5` indexes should be `0`, the first instance of `BH17 7EP`

`TA2 6LL` is at index `1` and `6` so in the new array the `1` and the `6` indexes should be `1`, the first instance of `TA2 6LL`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can iterate over the array and use `indexOf()` it always returns the first index of a value in the array. something like this:

```js
var destRes = ['BH17 7EP', 'TA2 6LL', 'OX15 4LJ', 'OX15 4LJ', 'OX15 4LJ', 'BH17 7EP', 'TA2 6LL'];

var indexes = destRes.map(x => destRes.indexOf(x));

console.log(indexes);
```

Comment: Love it; Works like a charm; exactly what I was looking . Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could map the indices with a hash table, without using another loop for [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```js
var array = ['BH17 7EP', 'TA2 6LL', 'OX15 4LJ', 'OX15 4LJ', 'OX15 4LJ', 'BH17 7EP', 'TA2 6LL'],
    temp = Object.create(null),
    result = array.map(function (a, i) {
        return a in temp ? temp[a] : temp[a] = i;
    });
    
console.log(result);
console.log(temp);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Doesn't `in` operator perform a loop in background ?

Comment: yes, but not implicit. hash table perform better than searches over the elements.

Answer (score 0):

**try this one**

```js
var destRes = ['BH17 7EP', 'TA2 6LL', 'OX15 4LJ', 'OX15 4LJ', 'OX15 4LJ', 'BH17 7EP', 'TA2 6LL'];
var newArr = [];
for (var i = (destRes.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
  var temp = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    if (destRes[j] == destRes[i]) {
      temp = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (temp == 1) {
    newArr[i] = j;
  } else {
    newArr[i] = i;
  }
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: You could replace you second `for-loop` with a call to `indexOf`